# How Would a Base Pi or Base Phi Number System Impact a Culture?

Tags: science-fiction

We use base 10 because that is the number of fingers we possess. However it's not hard at all to imagine a culture encountering infinite numbers like pi or phi, deciding those were special, and changing the base unit of counting. Some of the impact is simple to gauge: the constant dropping from geometry and physics equations. Maybe thinking in terms of circles makes things like alternating current more obvious.

Or maybe it isn't: you are in a world of hurt if you can not have a unit (1) of measure.

This question is world building, in my opinion, but it may be too broad for our rules. What effects would having a pi-base or phi-base number system do to a society?

Comment: If this is answerable it belongs at mathexchange. As ”is it possible ro construct a meaningful number system basen on an irrational number?”

Comment: In my opinion, this question is both far too broad, and not about worldbuilding.  I have VTCed as the second.

Comment: We use discrete  numbers because they're the intuitive way to start. The concept of fractions came much later. Starting off with irrationals, would simply lead to them dropping mathematics altogether.  The way math was developed is basically also the same way it is taught to children.

Comment: The question is meaningless. (HInt: *unit* comes from Latin *unitas*, one-ness.) The word "counting" means enumerating (a subset of) the integers. As the great [Leopold Kronecker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopold_Kronecker) said, *"God made the integers, all else is the work of man."* (And pi and phi are not "infnite" numbers; what they are is irrational numbers. Pi is a transcendental irrational, phi is an ordinary algebraic irrational.)

Comment: From a mathematical side of things, irrational numbers can be used as a number base: [Golden ratio base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio_base). That page has more Greek letters in it than the Odyssey so I don't really understand the math, but it definitely looks like it would work. As for how it impacts the culture, you may want to narrow the scope or else the question is a bit broad because culture is a huge topic: irrational-based music alone could probably be a full question.

Comment: You make one assumption: This impacts culture. There have been many different cultures with many different ways of counting. Could you perhaps elaborate why you think that this made such a big difference? Also, pi dropping from Physics equation is a bit of a non-issue. If you choose your units wisely, this happens anyhow.

Comment: Aside from the other comments, "what effect has X on society?" is always too broad.

Comment: An irrational base is great for doing math related to the base... but not particularly useful for everyday activities. It would be somewhat like the roman numerals, that were great for adding and subtracting but required special and somewhat rare training for multiplication, only more so. So basically the question corresponds to "What are the social effects of a number system invented for religious/scientific purposes but useless for counting sheep?"